# OpenCV Convert Bitmap to Mat

Tags: c#, opencv, bitmap, mat

I'm working with c# and OpenCV. I have a Bitmap that I want to write as a frame of video using the VideoWriter provided by OpenCV.  I've done this in Python so know it will work.  I just need the conversion step from Bitmap to Mat.

My (partial) code looks roughly like this...

```
VideoWriter video = new VideoWriter(filename, fps, frameSize, false);
Bitmap image = SomethingReturningABitmap();
// NEED CONVERT FROM Bitmap to Mat
Mat frame = new Mat();
video.Write(frame);
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the [Bitmap Converter OpenCV Extensions](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/b75b74b9-4126-5a73-6580-d07885a75e6d.htm) to convert my Bitmap to a Mat object in memory.

```
PSTK ps = new PSTK();
Image img = ps.CaptureScreen();    
Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(img);
image = BitmapConverter.ToMat(bmpScreenshot);
```

One could also do the below but then you will incur significant overhead for writing and reading the data from disk.

```
myBitmap.Save("TempFile.PNG");
Mat myMatImage = CvInvoke.Imread("TempFile.PNG");
```

I wanted to see what the difference looked like, roughly. I was processing a 1920x1080 screen cast of my desktop for 500 frames using each method and here's what I found.

On average, for the `Bitmap.Save/Cv2.ImRead` method, it took `0.1403 seconds per frame`.
On average, for the `Bitmap Converter` method, it took `0.09604 seconds per frame`. It takes roughly 50% longer to save and re-read the file using my home desktop machine. Core I7 2nd gen, 16GB RAM.